# "Переход на личности" — как это понимать?

Tags: фразеология, смысл

В очередной раз столкнулся с непониманием этого термина.

Я знаю, что в научной среде под ним понимают метод аргументации (обычно порицаемый), известный под латинским названием *argumentum ad hominem* или более узко *ad personam*: «Вы глупы и некрасивы, поэтому ваш тезис неверен».
Последнее и есть классический пример перехода на личности при какой-то аргументации.

Понятно, что вне научной дискуссии понимание может несколько отличаться. Но беда в том, что тут у каждого свое понимание. Например, логическую корректность часто путают с вежливостью. Понятно, что неприемлемо обзывать оппонента дураком, *но при чем тут логическая аргументация*? Это просто оскорбление, аргументом не являющееся. Аргумент начинается тогда, когда есть тезис, а тут и тезиса нет изначально.

***Как все-таки надо понимать подобный фразеологизм***?
Есть ли какое-то общепринятое понимание?! Можно ли взять за бытовое определение перехода на личности вообще ***любое упоминание человеческих качеств***?

*Вопрос отчасти навеян тем, что в "нормах поведения" сообщества прописана нежелательность упоминания "личных качеств", которые (как я понимаю по косвенным соображениям) модераторы принимают за определение самого понятия "переход на личности". Но это лишь пример, вопрос совсем не замыкается на этом случае, он у меня возникал вообще задолго до моего прихода на SE*.
**.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .**
Расскажу, пожалуй.
Пример "перехода на личности".

Мой преподаватель философии, светлой памяти Сергей "Градиент" Илларионов,  однажды, почти сорок лет тому назад, наглядно продемонстрировал зыбкость понятия.

Рассуждали мы о том, что такое "собственность".
Согласно философии, собственность — это отношение между людьми по поводу вещи. Ну тут не очень понятно было — и на перекуре я его решил *пробить на вшивость*. Вытащил зажигалку и заявил: "Я вот есть собственник этой зажигалки. Какие у меня отношения с вами?"
Умница Сергей Владимирович не долго думая дал символического тычка мне в лоб, заграбастал у меня эту зажигалку — и сунул себе в карман. "Теперь понятно?"

Я взвыл, сказал что это-де ***argumentum ad personam (переход на личности)***. Он вернул мне моё имущество и заявил, что это не *ad personam*, но проверка теории практикой.

Поговорили, называется...

Comment: По теме: http://wikireality.ru/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: По теме: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem

Comment: Почему «на личности»? Научный спор подразумевает аудиторию или спор «стенка на стенку»? Достаточно и одной.

Comment: @shampar Такой это термин, он в ед. ч. не употребляется.

Comment: @М_Г Оттуда. *Сарказм или личные оскорбления не есть argumentum ad hominem*. Собственно, этот факт и есть предмет моего вопроса. Могу переформулировать. Почему эти вещи часто смешивают и насколько это корректно.

Comment: @М_Г, если интересно, посмотрите добавленный в мой ответ офф-спин.

Comment: Очень интересно, но у Вас описка, кажется, в отчестве (в интернете пишут, что он Владимирович).

Comment: @М_Г Да, спасибо! Владимирович, конечно. Это уже склероз.

Comment: Наткнулся на такую фразу: «Великие умы обсуждают идеи. Средние умы обсуждают события. Мелкие умы обсуждают людей».

Comment: @М_Г, «А вот мне интересно, почему пригожинские пропагандистские сексоты не обсуждают обсуждаемую тему, а сразу переводят разговор на личность своих оппонентов?» — пишет неизвестный мне eugene_netchaev.

Answer (score 1):

> Как все-таки надо понимать подобный фразеологизм?

Всё, что прямо не относится к предмету спора, обесценивает обмен «прямыми» аргументами, ставит преграду, уводит в сторону и становится контрпродуктивным.

> Расскажу, пожалуй. Пример «перехода на личности».

Вот пример невозможности продолжения разговора *по сути* — из собственной практики.

Давние товарищи и коллеги по художественному цеху встретились через годы на обсуждении проекта за авторством одного из них. В приёмной комиссии Заказчика оказался второй наш герой, сделавшийся к тому времени главным художником этой организации. Его мнение и аргументы были обычно определяющими, и, стараясь абстрагироваться от *личного*, он не полез в карман за критическим словом и как профессионал, для пользы дела, посоветовал Совету не принимать проект без доработки. 
Следом выступил Автор и его речь была о несовпадении вкусов, об амбициях, о том, как губительно действует на творческого человека мундир. То есть — о чём угодно.

Answer (score -1):

По-моему, тут имеется в виду самая неприемлемая часть спора между людьми... Выяснение вопроса, при котором стороны никак не хотят друг другу уступать, происходит такое: 
1) отвечающие на вопрос высказывают свое мнение;
2) если кто-то из спорящих людей ошибается, то ему могут указать на способ, который тот использует для подтасовки, оправдания;
3) начинаются обвинения, подколы, оскорбления...
Третий пункт говорит о том, что спор перешёл на личности, и это уже не спор по поставленному вопросу, а перепалка беседующих, которые друг друга не воспринимают.